# Nested function using inline AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm new with AMPscript. I'm trying to make my AMPscript look better
Original script:

```
%%[
var @pointsBalance, @memberLevel
set @pointsBalance = AttributeValue("Total")
if @pointsBalance > 1000 then
    set @memberLevel = "VIP"
elseif  500< @pointsBalance and @pointsBalance <=1000 then
    set @memberLevel = "Gold"
else
    set @memberLevel = "Standard"
endif
]%%

<p>You are a valued %%=v(@memberLevel)=%% member.<p>
```

I expected something like:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm

That means we just need to write the script in one line.

One more question. At first in the second condition I wrote

```
elseif  500< @pointsBalance <=1000 then
...
```

And it didn't work. Any suggestions to make the code better? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For your first question you've provided your expected output, but what are you getting instead? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is any worth it... but if you really would like nested functions i would go like this:

```
IIf(@pointsbalance>=1000, "VIP", IIF(@pointsbalance>500,"Gold","Standard"))
```

Becoming this

```
<p>You are a valued %%=IIf(@pointsbalance>=1000, "VIP", IIF(@pointsbalance>500,"Gold","Standard"))=%% member.<p>
```

or

```
<p>You are a valued %%=v(IIf(@pointsbalance>=1000, "VIP", IIF(@pointsbalance>500,"Gold","Standard")))=%% member.<p>
```

but i believe the `v()` function can be left out.

Comment: Thanks Johan. I just realized that nested functions made the code hard to review. But it's really nice to know the way to do it :)